# Firefox whitelist reachable IP address using native user_pref (NOT using an extension)

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to restrict firefox to make sure it can send requests to only one specific IP (or domain, but preferably IP) using only user_pref directives ?
Using an extension like BlockSite does not block an XHR to a blocked domain for example.
I am looking for a solution that totally restricts outgoing requests to a given whitelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not possible to do this without an addon,

so either you have to rebuild firefox from source and add the restriction yourself,

or restrict access to domains/ips from the firewall which easier and more robust

and if you use windows I think there is also a web filtering, some sort of parental control, in users section of the control panel